# How to keep NSUserDefault settings in sync with in app settings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I have used NSUserDefaults to change settings in settings.bundle. I also have in app settings which I update using an observer. This works fine. When I change the setting in app, I update the NSUserDefaults value to reflect it in the settings bundle. But some strange behavior occurs then. I can change it once, but the second time when I switch it to ON it goes back to OFF directly. I am guessing the observer is being called then and something is going wrong. Has anyone seen this behavior? I do not even understand what is really going on.

Comment: Is the observer/action somehow being called twice to update your defaults file?

Comment: Yes it is. The question is why. I am updating the NSUserDefault settings just once. It is getting called with yes once and no the second time.

Comment: I can't tell you why it's doing this twice, but I have noticed similar behaviour of an action like this (where something get's called twice) and simply hacked around it so I could continue working. Sorry I can't be of further help!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that each time you are done editing the NSUserDefaults you sync them.

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];